# Throat keeps drying out during running

Tags: running, breathing

When I run, especially when I run for long periods of time, I end up having a super dry throat, and usually end up stopping running because I am doubling over coughing and desperately swallowing, trying to moisten my throat. It also causes me to gag, for some reason.

I am not great at nose breathing (it doesn't work for me), so aside from that, what can I do to keep my throat moist when I run?

Comment: Do you drink water?

Comment: I don't have that problem but when cycling long distances I eat jellies like Shot Bloks or just regular non-sports one like Natural Company products.  These encourage me to keep my mouth closed and most likely cause saliva production which keeps my throat lubricated.  The trick is to just suck them instead of chewing and swallowing, they last a long time that way.

Comment: Me too! Is something wrong with it? I want to know too. My hip also starts hurting but that just means I am de-hydrated

Answer (score 1):

#### Drink more water.

Seriously. Dehydration is dangerous, and dry mouth and throat are early symptoms of dehydration.